# Read msi with python msilib

Tags: python, windows-installer

I need to read an msi file and make some queries to it. But it looks like despite it is a standard lib for python, it has poor [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/msilib.html).
To make queries I have to know database schema and I can't find any examples or methods to get it from the file.

Here is my code I'm trying to make work:

```
import msilib

path = "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Desktop\\my.msi" #I cannot share msi
dbobject = msilib.OpenDatabase(path, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)
view = dbobject.OpenView("SELECT FileName FROM File")
rec = view.Execute(None)
r = v.Fetch()
```

And the `rec` variable is None. But I can open the MSI file with InstEd tool and see that File is present in the tables list and there are a lot of records there.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is suspect, as the last line will throw a NameError in your sample. So let's ignore that line.

The real problem is that `view.Execute` returns nothing of use. Under the hoods, the [MsiViewExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370513) function only returns success or failure. After you call that, you then need to call `view.Fetch`, which may be what your last line intended to do.